# Laravel Eloquent relationship only returns minimal results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Tables:

```
Posts
id | console_id | game_id | etc

Games
id | name

Console
id | name
```

Now when i am querying this relationship I am constantly getting the "Trying to get property of non-object" error. Now if i limit my results to say the top 3 (which is all i have in the games table) then it will run but anything more then that it will throw the exception... is the relationship wrong?

Relationships:

```
Game
public function Post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'game_id');
}

Post
public function console()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Console', 'id');
}

public function games()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Game', 'id');
}

Console
public function Post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'console_id');
}
```

---

**Update**

@joel @rashmi So actually dumping the $post I am seeing this on my 4th entry... it is returning NULL

```
["relations":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["games"]=>
    NULL
```

The first 3 return values. But then the 4th on are all returning NULL's. Again i have only 3 values in the Games table

```
Games Table:
1 | game 1
2 | game 2
3 | game 3
```

And actually on the third entry it it has a value of 2 but showing game 3 name

```
posts table: 
id | game id
1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 2 (but showing "game 1" text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your posts each belong to a console and a game - not the other way around. And hasOne means there can only ever be one, but each console and game can have many posts. So it should be like this:

```
// Game
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

// Post
public function console()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Console');
}

public function game()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Game');
}

// Console
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

If your tables are named consoles, games, and posts, respectively, then you don't need to supply the ids, so I removed them. You can just re-add them if you need to.

Comment: yea was just adding the specific names to avoid any other issues. 
So i made the switch and now running into "Trying to get property of non-object" in my postTransformer:  'game'         => $post->games->name,

The object being returned is Games though...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your relationships are not proper. It should be like this:

```
// Game Model
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

// Post Model
public function console()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Console');
}

public function game()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Game');
}

// Console Model
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

And your Eloquent Query for post will be:

```
$this->model->select(SELECTED_FIELDS)
            ->with(array('game','console'))
            ->get();
```

where SELECTED_FIELDS means table fields you want to fetch.

Comment: So i made the switch and now running into "Trying to get property of non-object" in my postTransformer: 'game' => $post->games->name, The object being returned is Games though...